# How to know big csv file's schema before importing into hive

Tags: hive

I have a big csv file which is part of my project and available on internet. This file need to be loaded in hive. Without knowing the structure of file, how can I create external table in hive?

Comment: The short answer is, you can't. If you're unwilling to define the schema yourself, you can use Spark `DataFrameReader` to derive it from the file then save the dataframe to a Hive table (but you may not be happy with the result, depending on what's actually in your CSV file).

Comment: Does your file have header, and do you have Hue in your Hadoop install? https://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-create-hive-tables-with-headers-and/

Comment: Do you confirm the structure is static or dynamic ?

Comment: If I open the file in hue/hive then I can know the schema. But without opening is there any way, any syntax like describe or select * from xyz limit 1?